# Disable future days after today in MaterialDatePicker

Tags: android, material-components-android

I want to disable future days on MaterialDatePicker.

Here is my code,

```
MaterialDatePicker<Long> datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTitleText("Select Date").setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
                .build();
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Material_Date_Picker");
                datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
                       
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

what i want is like this,
[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAgRt.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import com.google.android.material.datepicker.CalendarConstraints;
```

public class PastDateValidator implements CalendarConstraints.DateValidator {

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(long date) {
    // Get the current timestamp
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Check if the selected date is in the future
    return date <= currentTime;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}}
```

In Your activity

```
// ...



CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintsBuilder = new 
  CalendarConstraints.Builder();
  constraintsBuilder.setValidator(new PastDateValidator());

  MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = 
  MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
  builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());

  MaterialDatePicker<Long> datePicker = builder.build();
  datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```